# Dynamically Changing Hazelcast Server Log Level

Tags: hazelcast

I am using client - server mode of Hazelcast. Is it possible to control the logging level of Hazelcast server dynamically from Hazelcast client ?. My intention is that, by default I will start Hazelcast server in ERROR mode and in case of any problem, I want to change the log level to DEBUG mode without restarting the Hazelcast server.

Thanks
JK

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast does not depend on any custom logging frameworks and makes use of adaptors to connect to a number of existing logging frameworks. See some details here:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/logging.html

Most of the current logging frameworks allow you to dynamically / programmatically change the log levels. I'm at a loss here, since you haven't given any details of the logging framework you have used.

For example :

```
LogManager.getLogger("loggername").setLevel(newLoglevel);
```

will achieve whatever you are looking for. You can also change logj configuration file (logj.xml) in runtime and the changes will be in effect without restarting any of the hazelcast servers.

Comment: My requirement was to change the Hazelcast server log file settings from Hazelcast client. Example : dynamically change the log level of hazelcast server to DEBUG from ERROR from hazelcast client. I finally decided to use JMX connection towards hazelcast server using log4j2.